# whats wrong with code?Im making program to output largest number of 3

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to call a function to the store it as a variable name largest so can then output it. Help is appreciated.

I know it is a simple question but i am new to this so it is difficult.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int find_max(int x, int y, int z);
{


    if((x >= y) && (x>= z)){
        largest = x;
    }
    if((y >= x) && (y>= z)){
        largest = y;
    }
    if((z >= x) && (z>= y)){
        largest = z;
    }
        return largest;
}

int main()
{
int num1, num2, num3, largest;

cout << "Please enter three numbers: ";
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
find_max(num1,num2,num3);
cout << "The largest number is " << largest << ".\n";
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask]. *What's wrong with my code?* is not a meaningful question, and you have not described a problem with the code you've posted. Before we can answer a question to solve a problem, you have to first explain a problem and ask that question.

Comment: Start by reading the compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that. :-)

```
#include <algorithm>

int find_max(int x, int y, int z) {
    return std::max(z, std::max(x,y));
}
```

Or if you prefer,

```
int find_max(int x, int y, int z) {
     int ret = x;
     if(y>ret) ret = y;
     if(z>ret) ret = z;
     return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully how to treat of functions in c++.
Thereby you would find out that a function can return some value. For example, your function returns the largest of given three values. But you didn't take returned value.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Answer (score 0):

Define larger before if statement

```
int largest;
If ((x>=y.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. You had put semi colon after first line of function. And you have not used the value return by function find_max. In following code I have assigned the value to variable largest.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int find_max(int x, int y, int z)
{

int largest;
if((x >= y) && (x>= z)){
largest = x;
}
if((y >= x) && (y>= z)){
largest = y;
}
if((z >= x) && (z>= y)){
    largest = z;
}
    return largest;
}

int main()
{
  int num1, num2, num3, largest;

  cout << "Please enter three numbers: ";
  cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
  largest=find_max(num1,num2,num3);
  cout << "The largest number is " << largest << ".\n";
  return 0;

  }
```